# how to retrieve all values/records if parameter is is null using Postgres java

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, arraylist

I'm using spring boot extends `JpaRepository` and passing List integer to Postgres and sometimes we are getting null parameters, So when we got Null parameter have to retrieve all the records from Postgres. But am getting error `InvalidDataAccessRespurceUsageException: Could not extract result set`
I'm using below query:

```
@query(value=select * from table where (item in ?1 or item IS NULL) OR (CarNumber in ?2),nativeQuery=true)

List<Entity> find(List<Interger> item,List<Interger> car number):
```

Please guide me with better Patrice.

Comment: Sorry, what is your actual question? What works, what not? Any Exceptions thrown?

Comment: Hi @jhueg am using above query to retrive all records for item ,if item parameter is passed as null .But am getting error stating that InvalidDataAccessRespurceUsageException:Could not extract result set

Comment: 1) I would recommend to switch the condition in first parentheses (`item IS NULL or item in ?1`) since the `item in ?1` would fail if it is null. 2) I would highly recommend to check for null *before* executing the query and if null using a query instead that returns all records. This way your application logic is much more comprehensible

Comment: As NULL (operator) (value) propagates to NILL better use a UNION.  _(Double quotes forgotten?)_ As `item` is used as optional filter an other solution might be more elegant.